# Load images from local directory in Fabric

Tags: node.js, fabricjs

I am trying to load images from a local folder using fabric.js in node.
There seems to be very little up to date documentation on how to do this.
Most example use `fabric.Image.fromURL(imageurl)`

As far as I'm aware, this only works for web urls, not local paths.
Correct me if I'm wrong, but I have tried

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(imgpath, (img) => {
    ...
}
```

which throws the error `Coul not load img: /image/path/img.jpg`

Where

```
fs.readFile(imagepath, (err, i) => {
   ...
})
```

will successfully read the file, `i` will be a buffer.

What is the correct way to load a local image.
I know there is a `fabric.Image.fromObject` but I have no idea what type of object it wants.

I am currently loading the image into a 2d canvas object, converting it with `canvas.toDataURL()` and putting that url into `fabric.Image.fromURL()` which *works* but converting the image to a url is very slow due to large images. There must be a way to load the image directly and avoid this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using fabricjs 3+, that uses the new jsdom, you can use the file urls!

fabric.Image.fromURL(`file://${__dirname}${filepath}`);

Check here on the fabricJS codebase how they handle reading files in browser and node for the visual test images

https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/master/test/lib/visualTestLoop.js#L139

Comment: Awesome, this works. I never saw any documentation for using file urls, only web. Thanks.

Comment: well those are valid URLS anyway. But good point that can be added to docs.

Comment: I've tried using this code `fabric.Image.fromURL(require('@jewelry/assets/images/card/table.png')` and it works as well, but it needs the file-loader npm package as the project I'm handling is using webpack.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
    fabric.Image.fromURL(require("../../assets/mockup/100.png"), (img) => {...}
```